# How to generate Xero signature for RequestToken

Tags: vb.net, oauth

I am trying to connect to Xero from a VB.NET windows desktop app.

I am adding the headers using `request.Headers.Add("Authorization", authHeader)`
and getting back a 401 unauthorized error.

I am generating my own Signature, nonce and timestamp.
I suspect the signature may be incorrect.

I am generating using the code below.  Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong please?

```
baseString = String.Format(baseFormat,
                           oauth_consumer_key,
                           oauth_nonce,
                           oauth_signature_method,
                           oauth_timestamp,
                           oauth_consumer_secret,
                           oauth_version,
                           Uri.EscapeDataString(status)
                          )
Dim compositeKey As String = String.Concat(Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_consumer_secret),
                                           "&", Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_token_secret))
Dim oauth_signature As String

Using hasher As HMACSHA1 = New HMACSHA1(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(compositeKey))
    oauth_signature = Convert.ToBase64String(
    hasher.ComputeHash(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(baseString)))
End Using
```